# vbscript mathematical expression not working

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

In my asp code, I have 4 variables with different values.

```
chAmount = 19.99
totalRefundAmount =0
voidQueueRefundAmount =15.99
amount=4
```

when I execute following statement

```
if (CDbl(chAmount) + CDbl(totalRefundAmount) - CDbl(voidQueueRefundAmount) - CDbl(amount) < 0.00) then
end if
```

The if condition is true while it should not be  because the answer of above expression should be 0 and it should not go in the if loop but it is going inside the loop .

I am getting -1.77635683940025E-15 in the visual studio debugger for the expression `CDbl(chAmount) + CDbl(totalRefundAmount) - CDbl(voidQueueRefundAmount) - CDbl(amount)`

see this following screenshot of visual studio debugger.
http://screencast.com/t/73PyutXB07R1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `Double` you're converting to is a floating point.

Why convert to `Double` when you are dealing with currencies?  Use [`CCur()`](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13903.asp) instead of `CDbl()`.