# vbscript round to 2 decimal places using Ccur

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am using `CCur()` instead of `CDbl()` as answered in this question:

[vbscript mathematical expression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569944/vbscript-mathematical-expression-not-working)

But I want to display amount to decimal places e.g 3 should be 3.00 and 3.555 should be 3.55.

How can I achieve this using CCur() function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CCur() is a "Convert to Currency" function, not a number formatting function.

Use following functions instead:

**FormatNumber**(number [,DecimalPlaces [,IncludeLeadingZero [,UseParenthesis [, GroupDigits]]]] )

or

**FormatCurrency**(Expression[,NumDigAfterDec[,IncLeadingDig[,UseParForNegNum[,GroupDig]]]])

*number : The number to format.

DecimalPlaces : Number of digits to display after the decimal point.

IncludeLeadingZero : Include a leading zero for numbers <1 and > -1

UseParenthesis : Show negative numbers in Parentheis (500) = -500

GroupDigits : Group large numbers with commas (or the regional delimiter)*

Answer (score 5):

To fix to 2 decimal places without rounding;

```
curvar = int(curvar  * 100) / 100
```

To format for display (`3` -> `"3.00"`:

```
curvar  = formatnumber(int(curvar * 100) / 100, 2)
```