# Logic in Custom Rounding off - VB Script - QTP

Tags: vbscript, logic, qtp, rounding

I have a data file where decimal points aren't specified for a decimal number. The number is just described in the layout for the data file as first 2 digits as real and next 2 digits as decimal and it varies for different fields, the real and decimal part

So an actual number 12345.6789 is specified as 123456789. When I want this to be rounded off to 2 decimal points to match the value in application, I use the below logic

```
Public Function Rounding(NumberValue, DecimalPoints, RoundOff)

        Rounder= Roundoff+1
    Difference = DecimalPoints - Rounder
    NumberValue = Mid(NumberValue, 1, Len(NumberValue)-Difference)

    RealNumber=Mid(NumberValue,1,Len(NumberValue)-Rounder)
    DecimalNumber=Right(NumberValue,Rounder)

    NumberValue = RealNumber&"."&DecimalNumber
    NumberValue = Cdbl(NumberValue)
    NumberValue = Round(NumberValue, Roundoff)
    Rounding = FormatNumber(NumberValue,Difference+1,,,0)

End Function
```

However the problem with this logic is that I am not able to round off decimals when the number has 0 as the decimal value

For an Example, lets take 12345.0000 which I want to round off to 2 decimal points

My function returns it as 12345 whereas I want this to be returned as 12345.00

Any ideas on how this logic could be tweaked to get the desired output or is that not possible at all?

Comment: Hi, I misread your question. Can you please provide an example of how you are calling your Function; eg: for you last example, would it be called like Rounding (123450000, 2, 3) ?

Comment: Didn't notice this until now. I got this rectified. Thanks to you for bringing up the FormatNumber function. I have updated the code. I am calling number as NumberValue = Rounding(NumberValue, 4, 2). 4 - The number of decimal digits. 2 is the number I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the decimal places, use the `Formatnumber` function. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws343esk(v=vs.84).aspx - the default is normally 2 decimal places, but it is region settings specific when using the defaults.

Your script also has a small issue if the decimalpoints variable matches the roundoff variable - it will not populate `Rounding` with a result. I am also not sure why you are comparing DecimalPoints to Roundoff (-1) ?

I've revised the entire routine - it should do what you want (although I don't know what values you are feeding it) - So now it will work like this:

---

Doing 4 digits:

> Rounding (123450001, 4, 2)

Result:

> 12345.00

---

Doing 2 digits:

> Rounding (123450001, 2, 2)

Result:

> 1234500.01

---

Doing 4 digits (increments if > .5)

> Rounding (876512345678, 8, 4)

Result:

> 8765.1235

Revised simplified function that should do everything you are asking:

```
Public Function Rounding(NumberValue, DecimalPoints, RoundOff )

    RealNumber = Mid(NumberValue, 1, Len(NumberValue)-DecimalPoints)
    DecimalNumber = Round("." & Right(NumberValue,DecimalPoints), RoundOff)
    Rounding = FormatNumber(RealNumber + DecimalNumber,RoundOff,,,0)

End Function
```

Here's a working version of your Function:

```
Public Function Rounding(NumberValue, DecimalPoints, RoundOff)

    RealNumber=left(NumberValue,Len(NumberValue)-DecimalPoints)
    DecimalNumber="." & Right(NumberValue,DecimalPoints)
    NumberValue = RealNumber + DecimalNumber
    NumberValue = Round(NumberValue,RoundOff)
    Rounding = FormatNumber(NumberValue, RoundOff,,,0)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The Code is other way around DecimalPoints indicate total number and Roundoff indicates the decimal number actually required. The reason equated Decimalpoints to roundoff was to  make sure the code doesn't fail when I insert same number in both places. That should be eliminated while calling the function itself instead of handling that it function so I will remove it. I used your code but it doesn't seem to work but I have never used the Format Number function before so I will get it a try

Comment: Okay - I was curious if it worked if you were to call the function the other way around eg rounding("123450000", 2, 4).... I'll change the routine to go the other way and make sure it's reading it as a number, not a string. When you say it doesn't work, are you getting an error or it's just not returning the right value?

Comment: Can you share with me the values you sent the function and the result you were wanting along with the results you received from my function? One or two test cases would be fine. :)

Comment: Actual Numbers 
12345.0000, 9876.12345678

NumberValue1 = 12345000
NumberValue1 = Rounding(NumberValue1, 4, 2)
Expected Result = 12345.00

NumberValue2 = 987612345678
NumberValue2 = Rounding(NumberValue2, 8, 4)
Expected Result = 9876.1235   Thanks again.

Comment: You have written two different values here - ActualNumbers 12345.0000 and NumberValue 12345000; 12345000 taken back 4 places is 1234.50 ?? it would be Rounding(NumberValue1, 3, 2) to get three places back.. Never mind. I will adjust the script accordingly..

Comment: My Example was wrong with respect to that I meant to put 1234.0000. I added 5 by mistake

Comment: So Actual Number is 1234.0000 and NumberValue1 is 12340000? or is NumberValue1 1234000? because it makes a BIG difference..

Comment: Yes. I corrected my code which is working fine but it's not rounding off 9876.12345678 to 9876.1235 but when I try 9876.12346678. It does round off to 9876.1235. So my question is Round function doesn;t increment number by 1 if the next number is 5?

Comment: That is because you are chopping off the last bit in the conversion. Check the updated answer. I have swapped the parameters over and catered for rounding as requested.

Comment: Perfect. Works a gem thanks. But still wondering how my code chops off. NumberValue = Cdbl(NumberValue) => Number Value is  9876.12345
    NumberValue = Round(NumberValue, Roundoff) => Number Value is 9876.1234

Comment: Because you are chopping off the original full length decimal before you actually round.. best to round the entire decimal THEN chop the extra - otherwise it will not include extra decimal places when it rounds..

Comment: I think I clicked the correct too soon. Need to add the formatNumber function in the code to get the desired result since ROunding(1234000, 4, 2) => 1234 instead of 1234.00

Comment: Your routine is not working because you are playing with numbervalue and you are losing your remainder. Anyway I have added an alternate version of your revised loop that works your way.. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you won't be able to use the Round() function for what you need. Take a look at the FormatNumber() or FormatCurrency() functions as they have the option to "IncludeLeadingZero".

Take a look at the answer from the following link for more information:

[vbscript round to 2 decimal places using Ccur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581195/vbscript-round-to-2-decimal-places-using-ccur)